# TimeOfDay' is not a subtype of type 'DateTime?

Tags: flutter, dart

This is the code i use to show time picker

```
var selectedTime;

void initState() {
super.initState();
selectedDate = DateTime.now();
selectedTime = TimeOfDay(hour: 23, minute: 23);



}


_selectTime(BuildContext context) async {
final TimeOfDay? picked = await showTimePicker(
  context: context,
  initialTime: selectedTime,
);
if(picked != null && picked != selectedTime)
  setState(() {
    selectedTime = picked;
  });
```

}

This is the code i used to send data to another screen

```
SizedBox(width: 120,
          child: ElevatedButton(
              child: Text('Continue'),
              onPressed: (){
                widget.book.selectedDate  = selectedDate;
                widget.book.selectedTime= selectedTime;
                Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> NewBookFinishView(book: widget.book)),
                );
              },
          ),
        )
```

but when i press continue to send the value of date and time i get an error
TimeOfDay' is not a subtype of type 'DateTime? please help.

Comment: Did you mean `widget.book.selectedTime  = selectedTime;`?

Comment: yes sorry about that, i changed it but the error still the same

Answer (score 0):

You try to assign twice your `widget.book.selectedDate` inside your `onPressed` (you might have used the wrong variable):

```dart
widget.book.selectedDate = selectedDate; // 1st assign with a DateTime
widget.book.selectedDate = selectedTime; // 2nd assign with a TimeOfDay
```

And even if your `selectedDate` is a `dynamic` with the 1st assignation being a `DateTime` you won't be able to assign the value of `selectedTime` as it is of type `TimeOfDay`.

Comment: widget.book.selectedTime= selectedTime;
i change it to this but error still the same.

Comment: Then it means that at some point you have assigned the wrong type to your variable `widget.book.selectedTime`. I presume you have declared it like this in your class `var selectedTime`. Instead of using type inference you should clearly define the type of your variable like this: `TimeOfDay selectedTime`